# How can get the page id of a Facebook Application Page with Graph API for iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

I have the application id of the Facebook Application and I want to get the page id of that application on Facebook using Graph API to Like it(I have already done the Facebook page Like functionality), Can any one there help me out please.

e.g. here is some application on Facebook.

https://www.facebook.com/YepmeShopping?sk=app_190322544333196.

I just want to get the page id of this application.

Thanx in Advance...please someone help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the [Graph API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/): Make a Graph API request to the app id `@"190322544333196` and the URL of the page will be returned as the `link` field of the response.

The Facebook iOS SDK can help you with creating the request and parsing the response.